# Formalise a trick of computing expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

First let's start with a good old problem:

> Consider flipping a fair coin. Let $N_1$ be the number of flips you need to see the first heads (including the last flip of heads). Compute $\Bbb E(N_1)$.

We can do this by noting that $N_1$ is a geometric distribution. But let's do it differently this time. It's clear you have to expend the first flip. What happens then? If the first flip turns out heads (1/2 chance), you're done; if it turns out tails, then you'll need more flips, but the distribution of how many more flips you'll need is just the same as $N_1$. So we have
$$\Bbb E(N_1) = \color{red}1 + \frac12\cdot 0 + \frac12\cdot \Bbb E(N_1).$$

A smart observation. But just how to show it *is* the real expectation in the rigorous sense? Is there anything **slicker** than explicitly writing out the summation $\Bbb E(N_1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\Bbb P(N_1=k)$ and then decompose each $\Bbb P(N_1=k)$ by the partition formed by "first flip is heads/tails"? For what I have tried, dealing with the explicit summation will not give the first term $\color{red}1$ as a whole, which instead arises only from a complicated summation.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with random walks/Markov chains?

Comment: @saz I do know a bit. It's fine if your explanation involves them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables such that $$\mathbb{P}(X_j = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_j = -1) = 1/2.$$ We interpret $X_j=1$ as "$j$-th flip is head" and $X_j=-1$ as "$j$-th flip is tails". The random variable

$$N_1 := \inf\{j \in \mathbb{N}; X_j = 1\}$$

is the first time which we observe "head". Clearly,

$$N_1 = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if} \, \, X_1 = 1, \\ 1+ \inf\{j \geq 1; X_{j+1} = 1\}, &\text{if} \, \, X_1 = -1. \end{cases}$$

If we set $Z_j := X_{j+1}$, then this shows

$$N_1 = \begin{cases} 1, &  \text{if} \, \, X_1 = 1, \\ 1+ \inf\{j \geq 1; Z_j = 1\}, & \text{if} \, \, X_1 = -1 \end{cases}$$

and so

$$N_1 = \begin{cases} 1, &  \text{if} \, \, X_1 = 1, \\ 1+ \tilde{N}_1, & \text{if} \, \, X_1 = -1 \end{cases} \tag{1}$$

where

$$\tilde{N}_1 := \inf\{j \geq 1; Z_j = 1\}.$$

Since $(X_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(Z_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ are equal in distribution, it follows that $N_1 = \tilde{N}_1$ in distribution; in particular, $$\mathbb{E}(N_1) = \mathbb{E}(\tilde{N}_1). \tag{2}$$

Moreover, it follows easily from the independence of the random variables $X_j$, $j \geq 1$, that $X_1$ and $\tilde{N}_1$ are independent. Combining this with $(1)$ we get

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(N_1) &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \mathbb{E}(1 \cdot 1_{\{X_1=1\}}) + \mathbb{E}((1+\tilde{N}_1) 1_{\{X_1 = -1\}}) \\ &= \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) + \mathbb{E}(1+\tilde{N}_1) \mathbb{P}(X_1=-1) \\ &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} (1+\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(\tilde{N}_1)}_{\stackrel{(2)}{=} \mathbb{E}(N_1)}) = 1+\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}(N_1). \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll provide an answer using the so-called "first step analysis" trick, which is essentially in the same spirit as @saz's accepted answer but might be easier to follow for readers with only introductory level knowledge of probability.

The first flip has two outcomes: heads or tails, each with probability 1/2. So, letting $X_1$ be the first flip (0 for tails and 1 for heads), we can decompose the total expectation using the law of total expectation:
$$\begin{align}
\Bbb E(N_1) &= \Bbb E(\Bbb E(N_1\mid X_1))\\
&=\Bbb P(X_1 = 0)\Bbb E(N_1\mid X_1=0)+\Bbb P(X_1 = 1)\Bbb E(N_1\mid X_1=1)\\
&=\frac12 \Bbb E(N_1\mid X_1=0) + \frac12\Bbb E(N_1\mid X_1=1)\\
&=\frac12 \Bbb E(N_1\mid X_1=0) + \frac12\cdot 1\\
&=\frac12 (1 + \Bbb E((N_1-1)\mid X_1=0)) + \frac12\cdot 1
\end{align}$$
And note that $\Bbb E((N_1-1)\mid X_1=0)$ means the expectation of how many *more* flips you'll need after the first flip turns out tails, which you can just treat as though the game starts over and we "recount" a "new" $N_1$, so $\Bbb E((N_1-1)\mid X_1=0) = \Bbb E(N_1)$.